# Call variable in foreach list inside foreach method

Tags: java, foreach, jstl

In my code I call list of array from model profile

It has attribute username, col1, col2, on so on

And username has value, also col1 and col2, in this situation I want to use value in col1 that is tracking

```jsp
 <c:forEach items="${homeProfiles}" var="profile">
      <td>${profile.col1}</td>
 </c:forEach>
```

So if I call `${profile.col1}` the value in HTML is tracking can I use that value in another foreach like in this code

```jsp
 <c:forEach items="${homeProjectlist}" var="projectlist">
      <c:forEach items="${homeProfiles}" var="projectlist">
          <td>${projectlist.${profile.col1}}</td>
      </c:forEach>
 </c:forEach>
```

From the code above I hope that JSTL can call `${projectlist.tracking}` from code `${projectlist.${profile.col1}}`since the value of `${profile.col1}` is tracking

Can I use that in JSTL foreach ?

Comment: Could you write what you want in Java perhaps, it's not entirely clear from the question. Or at least provide input and expected output.

Comment: (also, not capitalising "I" is lazy. This is a professional forum, not SMS messaging)

Comment: I am not getting your question...You have written `forEach` in JSTL only and again asking for that...why?